# Character not at begining of line; not followed or preceded by character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to isolate a " character when (simultaneously):

- it's not in the beginning of the line
- it's not followed by the character ";"
- it's not preceded by the character ";"

E.g.:

Line: "Best Before - NO MATCH

Line: Best Before"; - NO MATCH

Line: ;"Best "Before - NO MATCH

Line: Best "Before - MATCH

My best solution is `(?<![;])([^^])(")(?![;])` but it's not working correctly.

I also tried `(?<![;])(")(?![;])`, but it's only partial (missing the "not at the beginning" part)

I don't understand why I'm spelling the "AND not at the beginning" wrong.
Where am I missing it?

Comment: This can give you a partial match `Line: ;"Best "Before - NO MATCH` because 1 matches and the other not. Should that be allowed? Like `(?<!;|^)"(?!;)` https://regex101.com/r/6LWXQB/1 Else you can match the whole line and use a negative lookahead at the start `^(?!.*(?:";|;"|^")).+ https://regex101.com/r/jU6Eue/1

Comment: I'm not sure how your third line meets your rules surly the second " in the line should match.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow partial matches, you can extend the lookbehind with an alternation not asserting the start of the string to the left.

The semi colon `[;]` does not have to be between square brackets.

```
 (?<!;|^)"(?!;)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6LWXQB/1)

if you want to match the `"` when there is no occurrence of `'"` to the left and right, and a infinite quantifier in a lookbehind assertion is allowed:

```
(?<!^.*;(?=").*|^)"(?!;|.*;")
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rLDu8e/1)

In notepad++ you can use

```
^.*(?:;"|";).*$(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!^)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fWoPIh/1)

Comment: I tried your RegEx in Notepad ++ and it's marked as Invalid regular expression. Looks like the problem is in the "|^" part. I'm still missing something? Thanks for the support!

Comment: @PiccionePolemico I have added a pattern for notepad++

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that not preceded by `;` means that it's also not the first character on the line to simplify things

```
[^;]"(?:[^;]|$)
```

This gives you

Match a character that's not a `;` (so there must be a character and thus the next character can't be the start of the line)

Match a `"`

Match a character that's not a `;` or the end of the line

Comment: Thanks! In online syntax checkers it works fine, but when I'm starting to use NotePad ++ it breaks and matches only the " at the line begining. Am I loosing something? :-/

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking for a regex solution, but, almost always, strings can *also* be filtered using string methods in whatever language you are working in.

For the sake of completeness, to show that regex is not your only available tool here, here is a short javascript using the `string` methods:

- `myString.charAt()`
- `myString.includes()`

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const checkLine = (line) => {
  
  switch (true) {
  
    // DOUBLE QUOTES AT THE BEGINNING
    case(line.charAt(0) === '"') :
      return console.log(line, '// NO MATCH');
    
    // DOUBLE QUOTES IMMEDIATELY FOLLOWED BY SEMI-COLON
    case(line.includes('";')) :
      return console.log(line, '// NO MATCH');
    
    // DOUBLE QUOTES IMMEDIATELY PRECEDED BY SEMI-COLON
    case(line.includes(';"')) :
      return console.log(line, '// NO MATCH');
    
    default:
      return console.log(line, '// MATCH');
  }
}


checkLine('"Best Before');

checkLine('Best Before";');

checkLine(';"Best "Before');

checkLine('Best "Before');
```

---

### Further Reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes